# Dynamically created accordion not working. Why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can someone tell me why this accordion is not working?

The ajax call works fine, and the accordion div gets created with the same structure as the accordion2 div (which is there to check accordions are working!)

The div gets decorated with the appropriate classes:

```
<div id=​"accordion" class=​"ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role=​"tablist">​
```

but that's as far as it gets. None of the dynamically created contents gets touched. And the div just renders like normal (i.e. no formatting, just the links and texts alternating, NOT an accordion!)

As you can see, I've tried scattering the calls to accordion() all over, but to no avail.

It's obviously something to do with the fact that the entries are dynamically created. But googling seems to find others getting on fine with similar setups.

PS I'm tired AND clueless, so it may be something stupid!

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#accordion").accordion({
                header: "h3"
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/blog",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(blogs) {
                    for (var i in blogs) {
                        $('#accordion').append(
                            $('<div/>').append(
                                $('<h3></h3>').append(
                                    $('<a href="#"/>').append(
                                        blogs[i].Title
                                    )
                                )
                            ).append(
                                $("<div/>").append(
                                    blogs[i].Body
                                )
                            )
                        );
                    }
                    $("#accordion").accordion({
                        header: "h3"
                    });
                }
            });
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                header: "h3"
            });
            $("#accordion2").accordion({
                header: "h3"
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="accordion"></div>
    <div id="accordion2">
            <div>
                <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
                <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
                <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for one you initialize your accordion two too many times
try to remove two of these:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
                header: "h3"
            });
```

but keep the initialize that is inside the ajax function so the content populates before it initializes the accordion.

Comment: I only started scattering them about because it wasn't working. Never occurred to me that multiple calls would screw it up. Your suggestion must have been the only configuration I hadn't tried! God, how embarrassing. I was reluctant to ask cos I KNEW it would be a DOH! lol. It's working. Cheers!